# want to Convert Java class to C# Class Xamarin Android

Tags: pdf, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have worked on converting HTML file to PDF file in Native android. its working as i expected. when i want switch to Xamarin.Android, i am not able convert the Callback.

```
printAdapter.onLayout(null, printAttributes, null, new PrintDocumentAdapter.LayoutResultCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutFinished(PrintDocumentInfo info, boolean changed) {
        Log.e("Finish", "onLayoutFinished" );
        ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = getOutputFile(path, fileName);
        if (null == fileDescriptor) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onError();
            }
            return;
        }
        printAdapter.onWrite(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES}, fileDescriptor, new CancellationSignal(), new PrintDocumentAdapter.WriteResultCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onWriteFinished(PageRange[] pages) {
                Log.e("Finish", "onWriteFinished" );
                super.onWriteFinished(pages);
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onWriteFinished((new File(path, fileName)).getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}, null);
```

above code i have done in native Android with Java.

```
printAdapter.onWrite(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES}, fileDescriptor, new CancellationSignal(), new PrintDocumentAdapter.WriteResultCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onWriteFinished(PageRange[] pages) {
                Log.e("Finish", "onWriteFinished" );
                super.onWriteFinished(pages);
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onWriteFinished((new File(path, fileName)).getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        });
```

**WriteResultCallback** when i want to call this callback in Xamarin.Android. It's showing need to create constructor. so that i created a class and inherit the WriteResultCallback in new Class with Constructor.

```
public class MyWriteResultCallbackt : WriteResultCallback
{
    public MyWriteResultCallbackt(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {

    }

    public override void OnWriteFinished(PageRange[] pages)
    {
        base.OnWriteFinished(pages);
    }
}
```

After that when i compile the code i am getting compilation Error

> /Users/apple/Projects/Sample/Sample/obj/Debug/android/src/md5a4074a9abd9040c154db052535adf080/MyWriteResultCallbackt.java(8,8):
>   Error:  error: WriteResultCallback() is not public in
>   WriteResultCallback; cannot be accessed from outside package public
>   class MyWriteResultCallbackt  (Sample)

can anyone let me know whether i am in a correct track or not, if there is way to do the File Conversion(HTML to PDF) in Xamarin.Android.please let me know the way.

Comment: Do you have a try with writing `MyWriteResultCallbackt`  in current class.You can show link of sample project.

Comment: yes i created in same Class @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: Okey, it's strange.From error log, callback can not be used in `printAdapter`.Maybe can have a try write in printAdapter.@Pandiyan Muthu

Comment: https://github.com/pandiyan022/HTML2PDF here you get the Source code @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: Thanks for code, I will chek it !@Pandiyan Muthu

Comment: After building project , error log same with yours .However I found a open source project (https://github.com/mikebluestein/KitKatPrintDemo/blob/master/KitKatPrintDemo/HybridActivity.cs).In it, not using `new WriteResultCallback() ` instead of using `new  
PrintDocumentAdapter ` ,and override OnLayout can avoid problem of LayoutResultCallback. `public override void OnLayout (PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, 
                                       CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras)` You can have a try .

Comment: Thanks @JuniorJiang-MSFT i will try once and let you know